# MessageSource getMessage method not working in Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have developed a Spring mvc application where I want to read some property value
from properties file located inside of weblogic server.

Have performed following steps:

Created a project specific folder appConfig in following path: `Oracle/Middleware/ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/wl_server/config/rmsConfig`

Placed the properties file named commonConfig.properties inside of it.

Have also edited `setDomainEnv.cmd` with following entry,

```
if NOT "%EXT_POST_CLASSPATH%"=="" (
   set EXT_POST_CLASSPATH=%EXT_POST_CLASSPATH%;%DOMAIN_HOME%\config\appConfig
if NOT "%POST_CLASSPATH%"=="" (
    set POST_CLASSPATH=%POST_CLASSPATH%;%EXT_POST_CLASSPATH%
) else (
    set POST_CLASSPATH=%EXT_POST_CLASSPATH%
 )
)
```

Please find below my Spring bean configuration file for this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd">

 <bean id="commonProps" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
      <property name="basename" value="commonConfig" />
      <property name="cacheSeconds" value="120" />
 </bean>
</beans>
```

In my Java Spring bean class I am refering to this as follows:

```
         @Component 
         public class LocationClient{
            @Autowired
            private MessageSource commonProps;

           public void showMessage(){
             System.out.println(commonProps.getMessage("common.line", null, null, null)); 
          }
       }
```

Now `commonProps` is **not null** but "common.line" printing **null** in console.

Please find below property file entry:

```
common.line=382
```

Anyone has any suitable solution to this???

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add your property file in classpath or in **WEB-INF** folder.

This is the note from the Java Spring docs.

> For a typical web application, message files could be placed in
>   WEB-INF: e.g. a "WEB-INF/messages" basename would find a
>   "WEB-INF/messages.properties", "WEB-INF/messages_en.properties" etc
>   arrangement as well as "WEB-INF/messages.xml",
>   "WEB-INF/messages_en.xml" etc. Note that message definitions in a
>   previous resource bundle will override ones in a later bundle, due to
>   sequential lookup.

Refer the link for more information: [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use `ResourceBundleMessageSource` instead of `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` in order to define your properties like this:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="commonConfig" />
    </bean>
```

Also make sure that `commonConfig.properties` is inside of your WEB-INF folder, for example if your application is appConfig then it should be on the root of your classpath: `appConfig/WEB-INF/classes/commonConfig.properties`

**Second alternative** if you need `commonConfig.properties` outside classpath, using your first approach (make sure that the bean id is `messageSource`)

```
 <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
      <property name="basename" value="file:/your/absoulute/path/commonConfig" />
      <property name="cacheSeconds" value="120" />
 </bean>
```

Comment: is there no way to put the properties file inside application server?

Comment: inside application server means that you need the properties file outside classpath? in that case `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` let you define an specific path no matter if it is outside of classpath.  On the other hand  `ResourceBundleMessageSource` force to use a classpath resource.